# I cant create an order with kucoin api with php

Tags: php

Hello im using that code to create buy order but it shows me that error "{"code":"UNAUTH","msg":"Signature verification failed","success":false,"timestamp":1517154443105}"

```
$ku_key = 'KEY';

$ku_secret = 'SECRET';

$host = "https://api.kucoin.com";

$nonce = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

$endpoint = "/v1/order";

$querystring = "symbol=POE-BTC&price=0.00000748&amount=5514.70588235&type=BUY";

$signstring = $endpoint.'/'.$nonce.'/'.$querystring;

$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', base64_encode($signstring) , $ku_secret);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . $endpoint);

$headers = [ 'KC-API-SIGNATURE:' . $hash, 'KC-API-KEY:' . $ku_key, 'KC-API-NONCE:' . $nonce, 'Content-Type:application/json' ];

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Kucoin Bot; '.php_uname('a').'; PHP/'.phpversion().')' ); 

/* 

YOU CAN USE THIS SECTION, I USE BOTH OF THEM WITH THIS AND WITHOUT THIS. NOT WORKING WITH BOTH. 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "symbol=POE-BTC&price=0.00000748&amount=5514.70588235&type=BUY"); 

*/ 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . $endpoint); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Could you explain, what you have tried so far? At the moment this looks like a bad password.

Comment: sir. this is kucoin api . kucoin is a bitcoin exchange platform. and i want to create a buy order with this code. but when i try this. it shows me this error.->
 "{"code":"UNAUTH","msg":"Signature verification failed","success":false,"timestamp":1517154443105}"

Comment: So you have a bad signature? Probably you have to put your own account keys and secrets etc to this code.

Comment: I have this is not problem. i changed and copy paste this platform sir. this is not related to key and secret. could you look at this link https://kucoinapidocs.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/assets-operation/create-an-order

I couldnt understand how to do it. but this page explain

Comment: @GokhanCava-ByJameson Have you changed the `$ku_key` and `$ku_secret` values?

Comment: yes sir. i have tried with real key and secret of course. this is not related with them. this is related with signature problem but i couldnt understand this.

Comment: IS THERE ANYONE WHO HAS DIFFERENT OPINION? PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error message today when I was implementing the KuCoin API in my trader software. However, I got it working. Please find my working solution below:

```
/**
 * 
 * @see https://kucoinapidocs.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/authentication/signature-calculation
 * 
 */
private function signedRequest($endpoint, $params = array())
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Must be synced, KuCoin rejects requests > 3s
    $nonce = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    // Build the data string.
    // Note - According documentation:
    // Arrange the parameters in ascending alphabetical order (lower cases first)
    $queryString = http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    // Splice string for signing
    $auth = $endpoint . '/' . $nonce . '/' . $queryString;

    // Make a base64 encoding of the completed string
    $signedStr = base64_encode($auth);

    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $signedStr, $this->secret);

    $headers = array (
        'KC-API-KEY:' . $this->key,
        'KC-API-NONCE:' . $nonce,
        'KC-API-SIGNATURE:' . $signature,
    );

    // POST is not allowed so we attach the parameter to the url
    $curl = $this->base . $endpoint . "?" . $queryString;

    // make the request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // do not print output to screen
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Tested with endpoint '/v1/account/balances'

```
public function getWalletBalance()
{
    $params = array(
      'limit' => '12',
      'page' => '1'
    );

    $balance = $this->signedRequest("/v1/account/balances", $params);

    return $this->_getFormattedBalance($balance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your params alphabetically in both the query string and post request. Their docs need a little improvement but this is stated in them somewhere.

```
$querystring = "amount=5514.70588235&price=0.00000748&symbol=POE-BTC&type=BUY";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "amount=5514.70588235&price=0.00000748&symbol=POE-BTC&type=BUY");
```